# How to create a filter to exclude certain characters in AWS Lambda using Python script?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, filter, aws-lambda

I am really stuck with my little coding practices

```
def get_zhan_created_snapshots(self):
    snapshots = self.ec2.describe_snapshots(Filters=[{'Name': 'description', 'Values': ['Created by CreateImage for ami-abc', 'Created by CreateImage for ami-bcd', 'Created by CreateImage for ami-efg', 'Created by CreateImage for ami-hij']}])
    return snapshots
```

In this method I actually want to NOT return the snapshots listed in the array

```
['Created by CreateImage for ami-abc', 'Created by CreateImage for ami-bcd', 'Created by CreateImage for ami-efg', 'Created by CreateImage for ami-hij']
```

How can I do that?

Thanks.
Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I created code to iterate through the list to do the filtering.

```
snapshots = self.ec2.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=['self'])
for snapshot in snapshots['Snapshots']:
            description = snapshot['Description']
            if (description == ''):
                #Do your thing
```